# store the command output in an array and print one by one

Tags: shell, array

This is my command:

```
cat httpd.conf | grep ^LogFormat | awk -F\" '{print $(NF)}'
```

Output of this:

```
commonsess
common
```

or can be any number of values, I need to store these values in an array and print one by one...using their index number.

Answer (score 2):

Using arrays or loops in shells is often signs of bad coding practice. A shell is a tool to run other commands. `awk` is the typical command to do complicated tasks with fields in text records. You want to call `awk` once for your task, not a loop where you're going to run hundreds of commands.

If you want to print an index and last field name for the lines starting with `^LogFormat`, it's:

```
awk '/^LogFormat/{print n++, $NF}' httpd.conf
```

No need for `cat` (which is for concatenating), nor `grep` (`awk` is a superset of `grep`) or a shell array or a shell loop.

Answer (score 2):

To strat with, using `cat, grep and awk` is usually wrong.  You now have

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep ^LogLevel | awk -F\" '{print $(NF)}'
```

To read the lines in an array you can use `read`

```
while read -rd '' -a array
 do array+=("$REPLY")
 done < <(awk -F\" '/^LogFormat/{ print $(NF)}' httpd.conf)
printf '%s\n' "${array[0]}"
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense as currently written.

Comment: I meant that your `array+=("$REPLY")` for instance doesn't make much sense. Where's that REPLY coming from? Why read blank delimited fields of NUL delimited records? (and there's definitely nothing personal against you :-))

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  `array+=..` is indeed useless in this case since the `stdin` is not user input but it's a file. And yes delimiter is set to indicate `NULs` or `\0` ending of the arguments passed to the array otherwise unexpected result can occur.

Comment: I'm with Stephane here. The `array+=`  seems not suited in this case. I've never seen it's use earlier though.. but it seems quite useful!

Answer (score 0):

**In short**,
you can use:

```
a=( $(awk '/^LogFormat/{print $(NF)}' httpd.conf) )
```

to get the words from httpd.conf into the array variable `a`.

You can access the elements by their index now:

```
$ echo ${a[2]}
common
```

**Explained and illustrated**

**Assingning** arrays:

```
$ a=( e1 e2 e3 )
$ echo "count: ${#a}, a[2]: \"${a[2]}\""  
count: 3, a[2]: "e2"
```

Some shell **setup**:

This is not needed for this example where we know we have only words as values, but in general, it is very important.
We need the option `-f` to prevent globbing if the values contain `*` or `?`.
Also, we should set the internal field separator IFS according to our data, if it's not simple words (and save and restore it).

```
$ # set -f
$ # IFS=$'\n'
```

Our test **input**:

```
$ in=httpd.conf
$ grep '^LogFormat' "$in"  | awk -F\" '{print $(NF)}'
 combined
 common
 referer
 agent
```

With your **original** command:

```
$ a=( $(cat "$in" | grep '^LogFormat' | awk -F\" '{print $(NF)}') )
$ echo "count: ${#a}, a[2]: \"${a[2]}\""
count: 4, a[2]: " common"
```

With the **shorter** version of @StéphaneChazelas:

```
$ a=( $(awk '/^LogFormat/{print $(NF)}' $in) )
$ echo "count: ${#a}, a[2]: \"${a[2]}\""  
count: 4, a[2]: "common"
```

Comment: You should also disable globbing (`set -f`) as you don't want that part of the split+glob operator here.