# move subshell output into an array in bash 3

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, command-substitution

How do I import the results of a subshell command into an array in bash 3?

I have been using mapfile to accomplish this in bash 4 as follows:

```
mapfile -t myarray < <(someScript.sh)
```

However, some of the servers I am working with only have bash 3 installed, and cannot be upgraded to bash 4.

What is an equivalent command in bash 4?

I need to be able to iterate the lines in the array, and perform operations on the contents of each line.

Comment: "perform operations" ? what kind of operations ? if you're just processing text then an array is one of the last things you'd want to use...

Comment: @don_crissti I need to do regular expression checks on each line of the array. Then, if a given line contains a given regular expression, I need to do some string parsing to process dates, look for substrings, perform math on extracted numbers, etc.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `awk` but then, without knowing the exact details it's hard to tell. Anyway, if you get familiar with `awk`, you'll be able to do a lot of that stuff without using shell loops and arrays to process text which, as _Stéphane_ said [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149667), is a sign of bad coding practice.

Comment: @don_crissti The shell calls a second script using a subshell. All of the terminal output from the second script is checked line by line for a few different RegEx matches. If a specific RegEx match is found, the line is parsed to extract a variable. Then the value of the extracted variable is used to guide the control flow.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially you can replace it with simple `while` loop:

```
function map_my_array()
{
  my_file=$1
  local i=0
  while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "${line}" ]]; do
    my_array[((i++))]="${line}"
  done < "${my_file}"
}

fpath="$HOME/tst.sh"
echo 'cat /etc/passwd' > "${fpath}"
chmod +x "${fpath}"

map_my_array <("${fpath}")

echo "${my_array[3]}"
```

Comment: This does not execute the script. The echo line does not print anything..  I need it itorun the .sh file and then move what the script echoes out into the array.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of [@NarūnasK's](/a/332136)

```
readarray() {
  local i=0
  unset -v "$1"
  while IFS= read -r "$1[i++]"; do :; done
  eval "[[ \${$1[--i]} ]]" || unset "$1[i]"
}
```

Example:

```
$ readarray a < <(seq 10)
$ printf '%s\n' "${a[2]}"
3
```