# merging multiple input to same variable in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to run a bash script that controls my fans based on hdd temp.

In the script I can add my fan to "ARRAY_FAN=/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm6"

So I am wondering how I can add multiple fans to the ARRAY_FAN variable so when the script changes rmp on ARRAY_FAN it actually changes the rpm on all fans, pwm5,pwm6,pwm7 and pwm8

Can I add /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm5 to pwm8 as individual variables, then add them to ARRAY_FAN, or add multiple lines to the ARRAY_FAN value?

This is the script I am trying to use
https://github.com/kmwoley/unRAID-Tools/blob/master/unraid_array_fan.sh

Comment: This is probably better asked on the aforementioned Github page.

Comment: Hi Eirik and welcome to unix.stackexchange.com. Please always include the relevant part of your script **into** your post. Since your question seems to focus on how to modify an existing script in general, please quote only a **relevant**, self-contained part of the script in OP. Don't expect many people to actually go through the whole script and sort it out for you. Showing that you isolated the issue goes a long way toward getting good answers...

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332132/72707) help ?

Answer (score 0):

For Bash version >= 4.0, you will find that an efficient way (of populating an array `arr` all at once) is to use the command `mapfile`, or its exact synonym `readarray`, as in:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(command)
```

Check your array content with `$ declare -p arr` and all available options and flags in your bash manual.

For example:

```
$ mapfile -t arr < <(seq 1 4)
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4")
```

Expect this to fail in general if your command output contain globbing characters such as `*`. There are alternative ways of doing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32931403/4906636), an SO post by @gniourf_gniourf.

If your Bash version is older than 4.0, please indicate it for a solution not based on `mapfile`, along the line of:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d $'\0' -a arr < <(command && printf '\0')
```